# Changing back the user rights to sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

By mistake and lack of knowledge I tried to change the current user to root privilege by typing the command I useradd -m -G root user3
Now I am  neither able to access this user as a root user nor a sudo user.
When I type sudo apt-get update, I get the response user is not in the sudoers file.
and when I try to run apt-get update , I get a permission denied response

P.S: I am running my ubuntu in a mac mini

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to give superuser permissions in Ubuntu is adding yourself to the `sudo` group, or manually editing the `sudoers` file using `visudo`, which has all the bells and whistles to prevent you from locking yourself out. See [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) and [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) on the Ubuntu Wiki for more details.